# Send email notification with attachment

Tags: vbscript

I'm writing a VBScript to send email notification when a file arrives in Test folder. I want to attach that file to my email. The file name is not constant. Each time a file arrives with different name.

Below is my code:

```
Const PATH = "F:\Test"
Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim folder: Set folder = fso.GetFolder(PATH)

If folder.Files.Count <> 0 Then
  strSMTPFrom = "errorfile@test.com"
  strSMTPTo = "test@test.com"
  strSMTPRelay = "127.0.0.1"
  strTextBody = "The attached file arrived in Test folder"
  strSubject = "File arrived in Test folder"
  strAttachment = 

  Set oMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
  oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
  oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = strSMTPRelay
  oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
  oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
  oMessage.Subject = strSubject
  oMessage.From = strSMTPFrom
  oMessage.To = strSMTPTo
  oMessage.TextBody = strTextBody
  oMessage.AddAttachment strAttachment
  oMessage.Send
End If
```

Comment: Also, what is your question? Are you unsure how to attach a file? Does the rest of your code work? Do you get an error message? Have you tried some method to attach a file?

Comment: I want to attach the file in the inside the folder

Comment: tried it's not working

Comment: So, did it work this time?

Comment: Yousuf, SO is a community, not a free personal assistant. If an answer did help you, please don't just disappear. Mark that answer as Answer. It is only fair. This applies to all your previous questions too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say what you actually want is a filesystem monitor. Something like this:

```
Sub SendNotification(filename)
  'your mail sending code goes here
End Sub

Function CreateMonitor(path)
  Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  path = Split(fso.GetAbsolutePathName(path), ":")
  drv  = path(0) & ":"
  dir  = Replace(path(1), "\", "\\")
  If Right(dir, 2) <> "\\" Then dir = dir & "\\"

  query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent" & _
          " WITHIN 1" _
          " WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile'" & _
          " AND TargetInstance.Drive=""" & drv & """" & _
          " AND TargetInstance.Path=""" & dir & """"
  Set CreateMonitor = wmi.ExecNotificationQuery(query)
End Function

Set monitor = CreateMonitor("F:\Test")
Do
  Set evt = monitor.NextEvent()
  If evt.Path_.Class = "__InstanceCreationEvent" Then
    SendNotification evt.TargetInstance.Name
  End If
Loop
```

The `Name` property of the `TargetInstance` object contains the full path to the new file. Put your mail sending code into the `SendNotification` function and have it attach `filename` to the mail.

Answer (score 0):

To find the newest file in a folder, use this code:

```
Const PATH = "F:\Test"
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim myFolder: set myFolder = fso.getFolder(PATH)
dim myFile
dim recentFile  

For Each myFile in myFolder.Files
  If (isempty(recentFile)) Then
    Set recentFile = myFile
  ElseIf (myFile.DateLastModified > recentFile.DateLastModified) Then
    Set recentFile = myFile
  End If
Next
```

Then just use its path to attach the file.

```
strAttachment = recentFile.path
```

Comment: @Yousuf I have changed the method of checking the value in recentFile variable; try it now please to see if it works